# send zip file using ksoap2

Tags: java, web-services, file-io, ksoap2

I'm trying to send a zip file using ksoap2 as client... File is arriving but corrupted, I think is something in my code when I encode it in Base64 (I'm using commons code)...

**WS**

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path.toString()+zipName.toString());
        byte[] toByteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(fis);
        byte[] encodeBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64(toByteArray);
        return encodeBase64;
```

**Client**

```
SoapPrimitive soapPrimitive = (SoapPrimitive) soapSerializationEnvelope.getResponse();
        String result = soapPrimitive.toString();
        byte[] decode = Base64.decode(result);
        String formPath = "C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\test.zip";
        boolean flag = new File(path.toString()).mkdirs();
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(formPath);
        fileOutputStream.write(decode);
        fileOutputStream.flush();
        fileOutputStream.close();
```

The file is ok in the server, I can open it but when arrives in the client it's corrupted

thanks...